# C# send generated classes from diagram through webservice problem

Tags: web-services, c#-4.0

I have problem with sending a object from my webservice.

I have created a diagram with a product Entity... then I generated the database... C# generates a few classes in a ...Designer.cs file.

In that file I have the class Product which with the following:

```
     [EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="WinkelModel", Name="Product")]
     [Serializable()]
     [DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
     public partial class Product : EntityObject
```

I created a webservice with the following method:

```
public Product[] GetProducts()
    {
        using (WinkelModelContainer wmc = new WinkelModelContainer())
        {
            var products = from p in wmc.Products select p;
            return products.ToArray();                
        }
    }
```

But when I start the WCF Test Client to test my webservice I get the following when I want to test this method:

This operation is not supported in the WCF Test Client because it uses type Product

Does anyone has a solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it... This isn't possible in C#. I have to create a seperate class with the same information and send this class with my webservice.